# Insert checkbox values to database separated by commas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, checkbox

On my .cshtml file, I have this form with checkboxes:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Clothing" name="Child1GiftTypeNeed" checked>
            Clothing
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Shoes" name="Child1GiftTypeNeed">
            Shoes
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Coat/Jacket" name="Child1GiftTypeNeed">
            Coat/Jacket
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Books" name="Child1GiftTypeNeed">
        Books
    </label>
</div>
```

How do I insert the value of these checkboxes in one single database column separated by commas?

(I am a brand new C# learner)

This is my insert from codebehind:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "Id,Child1GiftTypeNeed")] HGProgram hgProgram)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Save to my database
        db.HGPrograms.Add(hgProgram);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please state the question?

Answer (score 0):

You need a view model. With that, you can then map to/from a list to a string:

```
public class HGProgramViewModel
{
    // other HGProgram properties you want to edit

    public string Child1GiftTypeNeed { get; set; }

    public List<string> Child1GiftTypeNeedList
    {
        get
        {
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Child1GiftTypeNeed)
                ? Child1GiftTypeNeed.Split(',').ToList()
                : new List<string>();
        }
        set
        {
            Child1GiftTypeNeed = value != null
                ? string.Join(",", value)
                : null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your view, you just need to name your fields `Child1GiftTypeNeedList[]`. The indexing syntax, `[]`, is necessary regardless, as the way you have it now, only a single checkbox value (the last checked box on the page) will be posted.